# Calling a function in DLL so slow

Tags: delphi, dll

My program have several worker threads that calling a function in a dynamically loaded DLL file. The performance is slower than calling function in EXE file. My program made using Delphi. I don't use ShareMM. The function in DLL has many routines to read file into memory. The used calling convention is stdcall. Actually, the speed is very poor!

I have no idea since I just learned about using DLL. So what should I do to optimize the performance/speed of my program/DLL?

Sorry if my question is non sense. I am sure there is nothing wrong with my exe, I just moved my functions into DLL and the performance be slower. Please ignore disk/memory cache factor as I have mentioned the routines of my DLL.

Edited:

This is how my program load the DLL

```
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(pwchar(path));
  if DLLHandle <> 0 then
  @CheckFile := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'CheckFile');
```

In my worker threads, I always check the function using `if Assigned(CheckFile) then` then call CheckFile function.

Here illustration of my function

```
type
TCheckFile = function(const FileName: string; var FileType: WideString) 
: Boolean; stdcall;
var
CheckFile: TCheckFile ;
```

Now, the code in DLL

```
function CheckFile(const FileName: string; var FileType: WideString)
  : boolean; stdcall;
var
  testCheckFile: TBla;
begin
  Result := false;
  testCheckFile  := TBla.Create;
  try
    if testCheckFile.DoSomeRoutine(FileName, FileType) then
      Result := true;
  finally
    testCheckFile.Free;
  end;
end;
exports CheckFile;

begin
IsMultiThread := true;
end.
```

What my DLL do? It plays with TFileStream like convert file to pointer.

I hope there is something wrong with my loading code and the calling code.

Comment: Impossible to say without any information but there is no reason why code in dlls should be slow. Code is code. Doesn't much matter where you put it.

Comment: You've given absolutely no information we can use to help you. Without code of any kind, no information about what the function actually does ("The function in DLL has many routines to read file into memory" provides nothing useful), and "performance is slower than calling function in EXE" provides nothing to help either. Please remember that we know absolutely nothing about your problem (or your code) except what you provide in your question; we can't see your screen or read your mind. Kindly edit your post to provide more details, or it will most likely be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: The difference of calling via a proceduretype callback or directly is a single indirection. So that is unlikely to be the problem, unless you resolve it every time. That means the problem must be elsewhere, please show more of what you are trying to do (the loading code and the calling code)

Comment: And you call LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress once but then call the function repeatedly?

Comment: @David, Yes I call LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress once and call the function repeatedly? It works!

Comment: We were concerned that you may be looking up the function's address every time you called it. Since you are not I simply cannot believe that the code in the DLL is slower than the code in the EXE.

Comment: By the way, don't use `string` across a module boundary. It's not a valid data type for interop. You have potential for allocating and deallocating on different heaps. Plus you need the same compiler to be used for all modules. And certainly don't think about sending objects across the module boundary. In the function you have here, `WideString` or `PChar` are what you should be using.

Comment: You mean my code may be take a time to looking up the function's address? I don't understand your second sentence, you mean my question is absolutely non sense?  Okay I'll change the `string` const to `WideString`.

Comment: I dont think the question can be answered at all. We need to see the code of DoSomeRoutine. And you should not be passing strings without using Sharemem or FastMM. Also we need to see the threads code because I bet the problem is there. -1 for the question.

Comment: @CharlesSungkono No, you would have a problem if you called GetProcAddress everytime you called the DLL function. But since you don't that's no issue. I don't believe that your code is slower in a DLL. Perhaps you build it with debug instead of release. Perhaps you have range checking in the DLL but not the EXE. Perhaps you have different code in the DLL from that in the EXE. Whatever the difference is, it won't be the fact that the code runs in a DLL, or I will eat me hat.

Comment: @Rafael Colucci, one function that I use is `uSimpleTrustCheck`. I have tried to only use this function and the result has already slower. The threads code is just fine. I have used it for two years with D2007. Now I try to develop in DXE2 and I moved my function to DLL. No problem with the unicode.

Comment: @Still not possible without seeing the actually code. I can think it is right, but maybe its not.

Comment: @RafaelColucci, If my DLL use large memory because it load a big file as database into memory, is it possible this thing can be a problem? Because the DLL will need some memory again for example to read file into memory. I don't know the rule about DLL file.

Comment: @Charles It doesn't matter whether the code runs in a DLL or in an EXE. It seems to me that you have changed compiler and switched to a DLL both at the same time. Why do you suspect the DLL but not the port?

Comment: Yes you can read my mind :). What would be the problem if I changed the compiler and switched to a DLL?  In the beginning lines of `CheckFile` function, I set the result become `True` then I add `Exit', the program works fast. The worker threads work fine. I can't believe unicode make slower my program? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Sure Unicode could make a difference. It's very easy to end up with code that spends lots of time converting between ANSI and UTF16. Or maybe just there is twice as much data flowing along the bottleneck. The port is the obvious candidate here. Calling code in DLL really implausible as the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that resides in a DLL runs at just the same speed as code that resides in the host executable. It is exceedingly unlikely that moving code to a DLL will result in a discernible drop in performance.

However, you state in comments to the question that you have also ported from Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE2. That is almost certainly the change that resulted in the performance drop.

When measuring and comparing performance it is simply crucial to change one thing at a time so that you remove any possibility for confounding factors.

Comment: I thought if I use latest compiler then the results will be faster. My program **works properly** (searching files and checking files) but the performance **become slower**. I just done simple test to compare execution time of a function from uSimpleTrustCheck (you can google it) that I use in my program. Format:Compiler|1st test|2nd test|3nd test. DXE: 50937.91 µs|45894.93 µs|46083.98 µs. D2007: 18259.59 µs|26364.67 µs|22770.57 µs. This is just for one simple function and there are another functions that I use in my program :(

Comment: @Charles Depends on what your function is doing. Looks pretty clear that DLL is not the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is having to do with: " dynamically loaded DLL file".  Dynamic is ok, but once you load it, keep it loaded right?  If you keep loading/unloading for every function call, it's going to be slow (and a lot slower in the debugger!)

Comment: This is not an answer; it's another comment, and should be posted as such.

Comment: Actually thats not true. Windows has such mechanisms to avoid that kind of problem. First of all, windows does not unload the dll when you tell it to do so. It does when it decides thats a good time to do. Actually, once you've loaded the dll into memory it does not matter if you call freelibrary, windows will keep it loaded until your program closes. You can test it yourself. Just load the dll and take a look at the handle. Them, unload it and load it again . After that compare the handles. It should be equal. Because of that and because you did not answer the question, i am giving you -1.

Comment: @RafaelColucci Try benchmarking `lib := LoadLibrary('mydll.dll'); FreeLibrary(lib);` in a tight loop and see how many times you can do it per second.

Comment: @RafaelColucci That your comment is erroneous. There is a significant overhead on `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @David. It does not make sense. I am pretty sure it does not slow the loop. Of course you should compare apples to apples. What are you doing to compare the results? A code with only a loop doing nothing and a code with a loop using load and free library? In that case, of course the results are going to be different because a loop  that does nothing will be optimized and not get executed at all by the compiler. Please give me a better example.

Comment: @Rafael For one of my DLLs it's taking 10,000ms for each load/unload cycle. That's an eternity in processing time.

Comment: @David: Again, it should be a problem in your DLL. I tested it myself with a windows dll and got 10 or 0 ms each call. Test yourself by executing the follow code:


    procedure TForm14.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      LibHandle : THandle;
      vTimeInit, vTotTime : Cardinal;
    begin
      vTimeInit := GetTickCount;
      LibHandle := LoadLibrary('wtsapi32.dll');
      FreeLibrary(LibHandle);
      vTotTime := GetTickCount - vTimeInit;
      Edit1.Text := IntToStr(vTotTime);
    end;

Comment: @Rafael The windows DLLs are already loaded in your process. LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary just incs and then decs a ref count. The DLL I tested with is the DLL I ship to my clients. It's big, but that makes it a good test. Oh, I said ms when I meant  μs. 100 cycles per second.

Comment: I changed my code to use another dll, madCHook.dll which comes with UIB and got the same results. Try loading another dll that is not yours. I dont know how much time 100 cycles per second represents in seconds, but imho it does not matter. What does matter is the time it spends loading and unloading the dll because users does not measure time in cycles. In my case, 0ms each call.

Comment: @Rafael A cycle here is one load of the DLL and one unload. So 100 cycles per second is a frequency of 100Hz.  So each load/unload takes 0.01s. You benchmark is not realistic since it doesn't run for long enough for the timing to be meaningful. Run it for at least 5 seconds.